# How to use an AWS Comprehend Custom Classifier Model with REST API?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-comprehend, aws-sdk-comprehend

Can someone let me know what's the easiest way to use the an AWS Comprehend Custom Classifier Model for real-time analysis through a single API call?

I've built a model myself and I'd like to use it through a simple API call instead of using SDK.

I've tried creating a lambda function to invoke this model but the API keeps returning "502 Internal Service Error".

I am very new to coding, so if someone can provide me a step-by-step instruction I'd really appreciate!! Big thx to everyone!